# Which sentence is correct? (In spite of)

Tags: phrase-usage, grammaticality, pronouns, clauses, possessive-pronouns

As the title has suggested, I'd like to know which sentence using "in spite of" is correct:

1. John keeps working in spite of him feeling unwell.
2. John keeps working in spite of his feeling unwell.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: As the duplicate says, both are correct but "his" is higher register. I would use "him".

Comment: Or "in spite of/despite feeling unwell".